# RecyclerView Adapter's data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

So I have a `RecyclerView` and its adapter. Any changes of the `RecyclerView` are held in activity and adapter only notifies the activity which(and how) item of the `RecyclerView` has to be changed.

Here's an example of what's happening in the activity:

```
list.remove(position);
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
```

So the list data of the activity is being updated by calling `list.remove(position)`
And there is a question. Should I also update the adapter's list data and how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly should not modify the items of `ArrayList` in your Activity, as this will make changes to your Activity's ArrayList not your `RecyclerView Adapter`. Pass the `ArrayList` to `RecyclerView Adapter` in its constructor. (e.g. `feedItemList`).

Then you can have a method `onItemDismiss()` in `RecyclerView Adapter` with following method definition and call it where you want to remove the row.

```
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
    if(position!=-1 && position<feedItemList.size())
    {
        feedItemList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
}
```